# PHP site doesn't work on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, mysql, linux-mint

I started using a Linux Mint and I'm having a little problem. I have a project, where the main folder contains PHP files, and inside this folder there are other folders with images, JS files and CSS files.

It always worked very well on Windows 7, but in Linux it just isn't working. It's doesn't get the images from the database, it doesn't get the JS files and not even the CSS is working, it's like they just aren't there.

I run it all again on Windows and it's alright – it's jut on Linux that I can't. Anyone knows what to do?

I installed apache2, php5, mysql server 5.6 and php-mysqlserver and it all is working fine, it looks.

Comment: What happens when you DO go to `http://localhost` in Mint's browser? Do you get the Apache landing page?

Comment: Where did you put the project files? "Doesn't work" is rarely a useful problem description. Please describe *exactly* what you do and what you get as a result.

Comment: Problem solved, as posted in the answer bellow, thank you all for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the Software Manager to find out what version of apache2 you have installed. Starting with apache2 version 2.4.7 the new root directory for the server in Ubuntu 14.04 and its variants such as Linux Mint 17 is:

```
/var/www/html
```

Place the files for your (local) website in the `/var/www/html` directory.

Restart the Apache server to update the changes using the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Problem solved ! My apache root directory was /var/www, i changed it because phpmyadmin was in that folder ! So i put it back to /var/www/html, put  the folder there and the phpmyadmin there too and it's all working great ! Just the database doensn't seem to work ok, but i'll check it out here ! Thanks a lot ! =]